# Fast data manipulation in C# .NET: RRGGBB to Bitmap / C# Video / Image Processing

Tags: c#, performance, video, bitmap, x86

I am getting image data from a camera which comes as an array of ushorts from an unmanaged dll.

I have managed to get the data into managed land at a speed which is pretty good.

```
// cpp .NET
static void imageCallback(unsigned short * rawData, unsigned int length) {

    array<unsigned short>^ imageData = gcnew array<unsigned short>(length);

    unsigned int headLength = 512; // header length in shorts

    pin_ptr<unsigned short> imageDataStart = &imageData[0];
    memcpy(imageDataStart, rawData + headLength, length);

    callBackDelegate(imageData);
}
```

The data comes ordered as "RGBRGBRGB...." ushorts for each color channel.

The managed array is then sent to C# via a delegate. Then I have to convert the raw data and stuff it into a (8 bit valued) bitmap via the usual methods like so:

```
    public static Bitmap RGBDataToBitmap(ushort[] data, int Width, int Height, int bitDepth)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Width, Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        var rawdata = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);
        var pixelSize = rawdata.PixelFormat == PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb ? 4 : 3; // only works with 32 or 24 pixel-size bitmap!
        var padding = rawdata.Stride - (rawdata.Width * pixelSize);
        var bytes = new byte[rawdata.Height * rawdata.Stride];

        var index = 0;
        var pixel = 0;

        // scale to 8 bits
        var scalar = Math.Pow(2, -(bitDepth - 8));

        for (var y = 0; y < Height; y++)
        {
            for (var x = 0; x < Width; x++)
            {

                int Rlevel = (int)Math.Round(data[pixel + 0] * scalar);
                int Glevel = (int)Math.Round(data[pixel + 1] * scalar);
                int Blevel = (int)Math.Round(data[pixel + 2] * scalar);

                pixel += 3;

                bytes[index + 3] = 255; // A component 
                bytes[index + 2] = Convert.ToByte(Blevel); // B component
                bytes[index + 1] = Convert.ToByte(Glevel); // G component
                bytes[index + 0] = Convert.ToByte(Rlevel); // R component

                index += pixelSize;
            }

            index += padding;
        }

        // copy back the bytes from array to the bitmap
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, rawdata.Scan0, bytes.Length);

        bmp.UnlockBits(rawdata);

        return bmp;
    }
```

If I time this operation (rawdata to bitmap) it takes ~0.5 seconds. The frames are coming in at ~12 times per second so this is too slow.

Does anyone see a way that I make this operation faster in C#? Or does anyone have any guidance for another method?

The goal is to have a live video image in C#.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Per the suggestions below, if I change the for loop to this:

```
        // scale to 8 bits
        var bitminus8 = bitDepth - 8;
        var scalar = Math.Pow(2, -(bitminus8));

        Parallel.For(0, Height, y =>
        {
            var index = y * Width;

            for (var x = 0; x < Width; x++)
            {
                var idx = index + x;

                byte Rlevel = (byte)(data[idx * 3 + 0] >> bitminus8);
                byte Glevel = (byte)(data[idx * 3 + 1] >> bitminus8);
                byte Blevel = (byte)(data[idx * 3 + 2] >> bitminus8);

                bytes[idx * 4 + 3] = 255; // A component 
                bytes[idx * 4 + 2] = Blevel; // B component
                bytes[idx * 4 + 1] = Glevel; // G component
                bytes[idx * 4 + 0] = Rlevel; // R component

            }
        });
```

This goes from 0.5 seconds to 0.04 seconds. Nice bit about the byte conversion, that made a big difference.

Comment: Then why tag C++? You're only attracting the eyes of grumpy folk like me who are quick to hit the downvote button.

Comment: first why `var scalar = Math.Pow(2, -(bitDepth - 8));` is called x*y times? also why `if (Xlevel < 0) { Xlevel= 0; }` ? `Xlevel` cannot be < 0

Comment: Look up `unsafe` for C#

Comment: [even more](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7llyZb) ... results are almost the same ... guess what is faster .. anyway you will not get 12 Hz with creating bitmaps ... if you wana show this you should rather use GPU directly with this buffer

Comment: Are you on x86?

Comment: Can `bitDepth` be smaller than 8? Can `data` contains values larger than 255? How can `Rlevel`, `Glevel`, `Blevel` be negative? Can you use `byte` instead of `ushort`? Also like Selvin said, it seems that you can lift the calculation of `scalar` outside the loop.

Comment: You can easily parallelize the outer loop.

Comment: Hi All, thanks for the comments. I did an edit, and respond to you all: I tag c++ because I have the option to manipulate the data in in unmanaged land. Or, maybe someone is familiar with, say, OpenCV and knows that will help me. Yes, scalar should not be inloop (moved it). I will check out unsafe. GPU directly? How? Maybe OpenCV or Aforge.NET or similar? Yes, x86. Bitdepth >= 8. I removed the other stuff not relevant to this question (levels should not be negative, was for debugging). Yes, parallelize outer loop. Can you point me to an example perhaps? Thank you.

Comment: It looks like parallel and unsafe may be a good route, I will try to implement this and post back.

Comment: So now you can process 25 frames per second, right? On how many logical/physical cores? Do you want it to be faster? Using the GPU might be a good option if you don't want your program to consume too much CPU time.

Comment: I am now running as fast as the camera driver can push out images. Can you point me to a resource that can guide me for GPU usage? I have further image processing to do.